# What in my SQL query is wrong?

Tags: sql

My query is:

```
UPDATE Residents
SET roomStage = '1', SET roomNumber = '3', SET roomID = '26'
WHERE Id = '35'
```

Every column names are good, but I get error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: „Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'.”
```

I can't see the problem... But I am tired, so maybe I miss something..?

Comment: You just need one `SET`, the first one...remove the others from your query

Comment: And don't use string literals for numbers `'1'` is a string, `1` is a number in SQL

Comment: Oh my god, it's so embarrassing. You are right! Thank you ... I'm really tired...!

Comment: @Hackerman, post it as answer and in such case will delete mine

Comment: Done Rahul...thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Your set only needs to be there once.

```
UPDATE Residents
SET roomStage = '1', roomNumber = '3', roomID = '26'
WHERE Id = '35'
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify your `sql` engine, but, your query has multiple `SET` operators:

```
UPDATE Residents
SET roomStage = '1', SET(here) roomNumber = '3', SET(here) roomID = '26'
WHERE Id = '35'
```

So your query should be just like:

```
UPDATE Residents
SET roomStage = '1', roomNumber = '3', roomID = '26'
WHERE Id = '35'
```

> **If you are using `SQL Server` or any engine in the market, you should always as a first step check the documentation, like:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql